# Mirroring Picturebox Image in C#

Tags: c#, winforms, picturebox, mirroring

I have such a problem. I want to get this result[image]

I have the image on the left hand side, and I want to get the result as shown on right hand side. I have a `Picturebox` and my question is how to rotate the image as mirror to right ?
I saw this answer on this site:

```
capturebox.BackgroundImage.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate180FlipY);
```

but this is not right solution. Thanks for help

Comment: Winforms i supposed ?

Comment: oh sorry Forgot to write , yes :)

Comment: why is the `RotateFlip` not right? Does it not work at all or not work as intended?

Comment: already solved, I was flipping the BackgroundImage, but I had too flip just the image :) Thanks Franck

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to manipulate with Image outside the PictureBox

```
 private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Image img = pictureBox1.Image;
        img.RotateFlip(RotateFlipType.Rotate90FlipNone);
        pictureBox1.Image = img;
    }
```

You have an example [HERE](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.image.rotateflip.aspx)

Comment: Plus Because you introduce the easiest way to do that